# jenkinci/mesos-plugin can't automatically connect jenkins slave to jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mesos, marathon, jenkins-agent

I have followed the installation guide and I still encounter **issues getting jenkins slaves to connect to the master**.

My mesos slaves are all having a `jenkins` user. with  UID `1000`

`JAVA_HOME` is into mesos slave path as well.

## Version:

- mesos: **1.2.0-2.0.6**
- marathon: **1.4.3-1.0.649.ubuntu1604**
- jenkinsci/mesos-plugin: **0.14.1**

## Cloud configuration:

[image]

In marathon I have the jenkins master instance running in bridge mode :

[image]

I have consul and HAproxy proxying `jenkins-2.service.consul.50000`

[image]

I also have consul and HAproxy proxying jenkins master `http://jenkins-2.service.consul`

[image]

## Expected result

Jenkins master should be able to run jenkins slave in mesos by it's own.

## Result

In Mesos, I have a LOT of framework running, is it normal ?

[image]

When I run a new task:

[image]

The slave have difficulties to start

[image]

It is offline :

[image]

If I login on a valid mesos slave, and as jenkins user, I start the jnlp agent manually:

[image]

It does work :

[image]

I also enabled `FINE` Loglevel on my jenkins master :

https://pastebin.com/93C2qsYR

I noticed this :

```
INFO: Accepted connection #18 from /172.16.0.2:48806
May 09, 2017 3:47:29 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
WARNING: Connection #18 failed
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler.run(TcpSlaveAgentListener.java:213)

INFO: Accepted connection #19 from /172.16.0.2:49443
May 09, 2017 3:47:44 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
WARNING: Connection #19 failed
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler.run(TcpSlaveAgentListener.java:213)

May 09, 2017 3:47:59 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
INFO: Accepted connection #20 from /172.16.0.2:50088
May 09, 2017 3:47:59 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
WARNING: Connection #20 failed
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler.run(TcpSlaveAgentListener.java:213)
```

I rather not launch my jenkins slaves manually. Is there a way to get more logs or plugin flow explanation.

- Why does it refuse to connect to the jenkins master at the beginning?
- I have read about `LIBPROCESS_IP`, but since the command work fine, could this be related to my issue ? I think it is not.
- Why is the slave trying to connect on a different port than `50000` ?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I thkin there are multiple issues here. First of all hunderets of jankins frameworks is not good. Something is wrong in jenkins framework registration and this should be fixed first.

Comment: I suspected this to be a problem. Do you have any advice on how I can debug and fix this?